# Populate a MongoDB database with nested dictionaries using Python

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb, dictionary, nosql, pymongo

I'm a newbie with MongoDB. 
I would like to create a database that has the following key-values structure, similar to a python dictionary or a JSON file (or better, in pure MongoDB style, since it is a key-value database):

```
'doc name 1' : {
                'word number 1' : 'value1',
                'word number 2' : 'value2',     
                'word number 3' : 'value3',
                'word number 4' : 'value4',
                'word number 5' : 'value5'
                },
'doc name 2' : {
                'word number 1' : 'value1',
                'word number 2' : 'value2',     
                'word number 3' : 'value3',
                'word number 4' : 'value4',
                'word number 5' : 'value5'
                },
'doc name 3' : {
                'word number 1' : 'value1',
                'word number 2' : 'value2',     
                'word number 3' : 'value3',
                'word number 4' : 'value4',
                'word number 5' : 'value5'
            },
'and so on...': 'and so on...'
```

The summary of Python code that would take care of populating the database consists of the following commands:

```
"""CONNECTING TO DB"""
client = MongoClient('mongodb://localhost:27017/')
db = client['totworddb']

for doc in docs:
   fredDist = Counter(tokens)
   collection = db[doc]
   collection.insert_many([freqDist])
```

This piece of code, once executed, gives me the following error:

> pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError: localhost:27017: [WinError
>   10061] The connection could not be established. Persistent refusal of
>   the target computer

I certainly did not use the best way to complete the task I wanted, but I could not even find enough documentation to find at least a similar solution. I am very curious to understand how to work with pymongo.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to replicate the error you are facing. The MongoDB server is not running on your machine when you are executing this code. Once you have installed MongoDB on your system, and added the it to the System Variables(or, PATH variables), you need to open a command prompt and run the following command: **`mongod`**. This would start the MongoDB server on **localhost:27017**. You can now run your code on a separate command prompt and start inserting data into the MongoDB collection.

Comment: Thank you very much for the suggestion. As soon as I return to work with mongo, I will follow your advice!